# GeoJsonPoint in spring boot data mongodb throws errors

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I got a problem with Spring Boot Data MongoDB.

I attached my code with dto below. Every time I try to insert new document with GeoJsonPoint object, I get the `com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: Write failed with error code 16804 and error message 'location object expected, location array not in correct format'` exception.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.GeoSpatialIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.Date;

@Document(collection = "collection_2")
public class SingleBusStop {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed
    private GeoJsonPoint location;

    private DayType dayType;

    private String lineNumber;

    //getters, setters

}
```

I got some other collection in the same project, where I insert some data with no problems (also with GeoJsonPoint). For some reason I can't insert data to collection_2. I am using Mongo 3.4.2. My pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<groupId>pl.server.map</groupId>
<artifactId>Utils</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**UPDATE**

> @GeoSpatialIndex

is by default `2d` index, to avoid problems it must be set to `2dsphere`- in case of this problem just switch index type in annotation:

> @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472023/location-object-expected-location-array-not-in-correct-format)

> MongoDB 2d index requires the legacy coordinates pairs format, which is just an array of coordinates like [1, 2]

So you may need to change the type of your field SingleBusStop.location.

[GeoSpatialIndexed](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/GeoSpatialIndexed.html) allows for some configuration, the parameter 'name' may help.

Comment: I really wanted to use this GeoJsonPoint type, I figured out that index must be 2dsphere to get it working.